# Enabling link layer PDU size of 251 for Bluetooth LE in Android 10

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE app on an Arduino Nano that continously sends IMU-data to a custom app I have developed for an Android phone. When I am sniffing the on-the-air traffic it seems that the phone is requesting a link layer PDU size of 27. If I would able to increase this to 251, it would require fewer link layer packets (and hence a lower overhead). The phone is a Motorola Edge which implements Bluetooth 5.1. The Android version is 10.

I have not found any settings in the Bluetooth API that controls this. Is it even possible to achieve this?

Upon connection the Arduino (the slave) sends an LL_LENGTH_REQ with 251 RX/TX octets to the master (the phone). The LL_LENGTH_RSP message from the phone looks like below in Wireshark, which might explain why the PDU size of 27 is selected.

```
Frame 294: 29 bytes on wire (232 bits), 29 bytes captured (232 bits)
Bluetooth
Bluetooth Low Energy RF Info
Bluetooth Low Energy Link Layer
    Access Address: 0x88c78ca1
    .... ..00 = Coding Indicator: FEC Block 2 coded using S=8 (0)
    [Master Address: 51:7a:c0:c9:6e:81 (51:7a:c0:c9:6e:81)]
    [Slave Address: ca:8b:68:49:aa:7a (ca:8b:68:49:aa:7a)]
    Data Header: 0x090f
        .... ..11 = LLID: Control PDU (0x3)
        .... .1.. = Next Expected Sequence Number: 1
        .... 1... = Sequence Number: 1 [OK]
        ...0 .... = More Data: False
        000. .... = RFU: 0
        Length: 9
    Control Opcode: LL_LENGTH_RSP (0x15)
    Max RX octets: 251
    Max RX time: 17040 microseconds
    Max TX octets: 27
    Max TX time: 2704 microseconds
    CRC: 0x000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the MTU by calling [requestMtu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt#requestMtu(int)) after your connection is established. You will receive the [onMtuChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback#onMtuChanged(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) callback afterwards. Start your service discovery after a successful MTU request.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought I was doing that. In the `onServicesDiscovered` callback I am invoking

`requestMtu(device, 512)`

Comment: I just tried to change the order of the calls so that `requestMtu` comes before `discoverServices`. But I get the same result, i.e., the link layer PDU size is still 27 bytes.

D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=CA:8B:68:49:AA:7A 
 interval=6latency=0 timeout=500 status=0  D/BluetoothGatt: onConfigureMTU() - Device=CA:8B:68:49:AA:7A mtu=512 status=0
W/BleService$GattCallback: ATT MTU changed to 512, success: true
D/BluetoothGatt: discoverServices() - device: CA:8B:68:49:AA:7A
D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=CA:8B:68:49:AA:7A Status=0